# Convert binary back to ascii in python

Tags: python, binary, ascii

So i have a function that converts an alphabet character to it's binary.

```
def toBinary(char):
    return "".join([format(ord(char), '#010b')[2:]])
```

For example, toBinary('a') gives me

```
01100001
```

How do i convert 01100001 back to the ascii 'a'?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be

```
c = chr(int(s, 2))
```

where s is the binary string.

Comment: what does the 2 represents?

Comment: The base in which you want to convert the number in. The default value is 10.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
chr(int('01100001',2))
```